# Unable to access picklist value in apex

Tags: visualforce, picklist

I am developing VF page and have couple of pick list values but I can't access any of the selected picklist value in apex controller.

I have modified a code little for simplicity.
I am getting null value in the executeFilter method for selectedFilterId. Can you help what I am missing here?

Thanks!

```
    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:selectList size="1" id="filterValueSelector" value="{!selectedFilterId}" style="width:100px;">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!filterValues}" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!executeFilter}" />
            </apex:selectList>  
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>


public String selectedFilterId {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> getFilterValues(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.addAll( MyFilterLayoutFunctions_ims.getFilters());
        return options;
    }
    public void executeFilter(){
        System.debug('*******Selected Filter ID: *******'+ selectedFilterId );      
    }
```

Comment: What if you add a rerender to the action support?

Comment: Thanks Eric. I already have a rerender in my code I have just removed it in the above snippet.

Comment: when you look at the debug log - do you not see the setter for `selectedFilterId` being invoked?  and, a wild guess - if above is an edited snippet - any chance in your code under test that the event name is not `onchange` - it is case sensitive I believe

Comment: Thanks! Its working now. There was an issue with my rerender tag. Its working after fixing it. Thanks again for help!

Comment: @user360 - So what was the issue since you already had a rerender?

Comment: @Eric, Earlier I was trying to rerender a div. I changed it to apex:form and it worked.

Comment: @user360 - Ahh - Just in case you do not need a form, you can use <apex:outputpanel layout="block"> to render a div that you can rerender

Comment: oh ok - Thanks Eric! I will try that. Appreciate your help!

Comment: If this is solved,I think it is helpful if we can put the solution in Answer so it beneficial for others.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric  mentioned in his earlier comment, after adding rerender to the action support I am able to access the pick list value in the controller.